# How to combine the common code to create a generic method?

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I have below classes with which I generate a request object and serialize the response to get a JSON string. The definition of classes are as follows

*PortfolioResponse & StocksInfo* classes are for mentioning purpose as they contain a lot many fields which I would not be able to write here.

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseInfoRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Token { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class StocksInfoRequest : BaseInfoRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SomeKey { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class PortfolioInfoRequest : BaseInfoRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PortfolioId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string SomeKey { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class StocksInfoResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "stocks")]
    public StocksInfo StocksInfo { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "pfolio")]
    public PortfolioResponse PortfolioInfo { get; set; }
}

public class PortfolioResponse
{
}

public class StocksInfo
{
}
```

Now, to get the data from different other classes and services in project I use below two methods in let's say class **Sample**

```
    private string GetsStocksInformation(StocksInfoRequest request)
    {
        var response = new StocksInfoResponse();

        if (ValidateRequestToken(request) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.SomeKey))
        {
            response.Message =
                GetsResponse().ErrorMessage;
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
        }
        response.StocksInfo = GetsStocksInfo(request);
        response.Success = true;
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
    }

    private string GetsPortfolioInformation(PortfolioInfoRequest request)
    {
        var response = new StocksInfoResponse();

        if (!ValidateRequestToken(request) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.SomeKey) ||
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.PortfolioId))
        {
            response.Message =
                GetsResponse().ErrorMessage;
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
        }
        response.PortfolioInfo = GetsPortfolioInfo(request.SomeKey, request.PortfolioId);
        response.Success = true;
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
    }
```

Now, if you look closely enough both the methods are almost same except condition

*if (ValidateRequestToken(request) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.SomeKey))* &&

*response.StocksInfo = GetsStocksInfo(request);*

Apart from above two, both the methods do more or less same things. The definition of **ValidateRequestToken** is below

```
    private bool ValidateRequestToken(BaseInfoRequest request)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

How do I combine both methods to create a generic method ?

Comment: So you need a generic implementation or more flexible code?

Comment: I am looking for a generic implementation but if it does not complicate the code too much.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a more abstract method and use the Specification Pattern to pass in a predicate for the test to check if the error message needs to be retrieved.

Comment: I missed you where also setting different responses. How does the GetXxxInfo methods look like?

Comment: @MBL: Methods GetsStocksInfo and GetsPortfolioInfo have different implementations. I was thinking may be if we can parameterize them using delegates ??? Possibility ??? If you still need specific details I can provide those as well